# Detecting that the peer's browser was closed in a webrtc videochat

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, html5-video, webrtc

I've been implementing a webrtc videochat.

Everything is working smoothly except for the case when the peer closes the browser.

I've been trying to handle this event by implementing an onended callback on the remote mediastream. Though, this callback does not seem to ever be called.

How can I detect that the peer's browser has been closed or that the connection was finished on the other side?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use the ICE connection status to determine this. If you disconnect one peer it takes some seconds (~5?) to recoginize it, but it works even without a signalling server.

(assuming you called your peer connection `pc`)

```
pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = function() {
    if(pc.iceConnectionState == 'disconnected') {
        console.log('Disconnected');
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason this event does not seem to get fired in my implementation (Chrome 40)

Comment: @LouisLC I just checked and for me it works fine on version 40.0.2214.115. Maybe you should check if the `oniceconnectionstatechange` is spelled correctly? Afaik the connection should first be set to complete before this can fire, but I suggest you to look it up in the [spec](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/) to see if I missed anything.

Comment: Yes indeed that was a simple spelling problem! Thank you Marijn. Could you edit your initial answer to replace your "onineconnectionstatechange" by "oniceconnectionstatechange"? I am not allowed to edit.

Comment: @LouisLC Now I see, I wrote it wrong myself. Sorry! Didn't even see that yesterday (though it is correct in my own version of the code).

Answer (score 8):

Use signaling gateway to send message to all connected peers that you're leaving; like this:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function () {
    userLeft();
}, false);

window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 116)
        userLeft();
}, false);

function userLeft() {
    signalingGateway.send({
        userLeft: true,
        whoLeft: 'user-id'
    });
}

signalingGateway.on('message', function (signal) {
    if (signal.userLeft && signal.whoLeft != 'current-user-id') {
        var relevantPeer = listOfPeers[signal.whoLeft];
        if (relevantPeer) {
            relevantPeer.close();
            relevantPeer = null;
        }

        var relevantLocalStreams = listOfLocalStreams[signal.whoLeft];
        if (relevantLocalStreams.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < relevantLocalStreams.length; i++) {
                if (relevantLocalStreams[i].stop) {
                    relevantLocalStreams[i].stop();
                }

                // it is suggested to stop media tracks instead!
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Remember, it is possible to detect whether remote media stream stopped receiving RTP packets using getStats API; however, you need to rely on predefined variables/names!

Comment: I do not have a full signaling gateway for now.

Comment: Hello Muaz, i really like your webRTC works! I'm curious why are you suggesting using signalling gateway here, is it impossible to throw message directly through DataChannel to peers onbeforeunload? And also onbeforeunload way will fail if user's browser/pc will crash. Is there any workaround in this scenario? One way can be making a heartbeat on a websocket signalling server side and detect disconenction this way, but maybe you can suggest something better?

Comment: `iceState=disconnected` relies on STUN-binding requests that are continuously made for the lifetime of the session. This method isn't considered a reliable solution in realtime applications that's why all WebRTC service providers (TokBox, EasyRTC etc.) handles presence/etc. detection on signaling end. Manually checking heartbeats on server or listening `disconnect` evens can produce better/reliable experience. DataChannels can auto disconnect many times in a live session that's why `channel.onclose` isn't a good handler. A channel can close if you try to send larger message than 64k or so on.

Answer (score 4):

I am using a solution like this:

```
const connection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
connection.onconnectionstatechange = () => {
    const connectionStatus = connection.connectionState;
    if (["disconnected", "failed", "closed"].includes(connectionStatus)) {
        console.log("disconnected");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. I've solved this by closing the connection at the desired moment(eg. on destructor).

A <- connected -> B

...

Close(A); // after this, B's ice status will go almost instantly to 'kDisconnected'.

Answer (score -3):

Just Use

```
 connection.onclose = function(event){
    event.useid // gives the connection closed userid
 }
```

Comment: what type of variable is 'connection' in your example? Is it a data channel? Because data channel does not detect closing on remote peer