# Javascript/jQuery beforeunload and unload not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await, axios

I have a page where I want my script to let the server know that the user went offline when the browser/tab/page is closed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Inform the server that the user went online
    setStatus('online');

    // Inform the server that the user went offline
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
        setStatus('offline');
    });

    // Inform the server that the user went offline
    $(window).on('unload', function() {
        setStatus('offline');
    });
});

async function setStatus(status) {
    let { data } = await axios.post('/status', { status: status });
}
```

The part where I have `setStatus('online');` works but I can never seem to set the status to `offline` when I close the page/tab/browser.

Comment: Trying to do asynchronous operations in unload events has never been reliable. Try using the more modern [Navigator.sendBeacon()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon)

Answer (score 0):

Looking around, I found this really nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21280418/910564) - I just had to put this on my `server.js` file:

```js
peer.oniceconnectionstatechange = function() {
    if(peer.iceConnectionState == 'disconnected') {
        console.log('Disconnected');
    }
}
```

It does take a few seconds before it registers that the peer has dropped but at least it's always firing and that's reliable enough for me.